# Is it possible to insert a tikz image in the part title page?

Tags: tikz-pgf, parts

I wish to insert a picture generated by tikz in the part title page (PTP).

In the following **Minimal working example** I've defined a \newcommand called *\geo* to generate a drawing with tikz. Then I invoke \geo before the PTP, but a page break occurs automatically, leaving the image on a page before the PTP.

Would it be possible to avoid that page break so that the image and title are on the same page?

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft, etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz, ifthen, bclogo}

%----------<<< tikz example >>>----------

\newcommand{\geo} {
    \usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (start) [draw,shape=ellipse] {};
        \foreach \angle in {-180, -178, ..., 180}
        \draw (node cs:name=start,angle=\angle)
        .. controls +(\angle:5cm) and +(0,0) .. (0,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
```

%----------<<< END of tikz example >>>----------

```
\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    
    \begin{center}
        \geo
    \end{center}

    \part{Special Functions.}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You could use `\AddToHookNext{shipout/background}{\put(.5\paperwidth,-.5\paperheight){<your stuff>}}` before `\part` (but perhaps there are cleaner solutions).

Comment: Thank you, Skillmon. I've found yet the solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg

Comment: Yes, egreg is the solution :P

Answer (score 1):

This answer is the solution: https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/4427/egreg

```
\documentclass[a4paper,14pt,twoside,reqno]{extbook}
\usepackage[margin=28mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsthm,mathpazo}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tocloft, etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz, ifthen, bclogo}
\usetikzlibrary {shapes.geometric}

% ----------<<< tikz example >>>----------
\newcommand{\geo} {     
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \node (start) [draw,shape=ellipse] {};
        \foreach \angle in {-180, -178, ..., 180}
        \draw (node cs:name=start,angle=\angle)
        .. controls +(\angle:5cm) and +(0,0) .. (0,5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
}
% ----------<<< END of tikz example >>>----------

% ----------<<< Definition of absolutelynopagebreak by egreg >>>----------
\newenvironment{absolutelynopagebreak}
{\par\nobreak\vfil\penalty0\vfilneg
    \vtop\bgroup}
{\par\xdef\tpd{\the\prevdepth}\egroup
    \prevdepth=\tpd}
% ----------<<< END of Definition of absolutelynopagebreak >>>----------

\begin{document}
    \pagestyle{plain}
    
    \begin{absolutelynopagebreak}
       \part{Special functions.}
        
        \begin{center}
            \geo
        \end{center}

    \end{absolutelynopagebreak}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: tikz imagen in part title page]

Comment: Don't put `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` in the `\geo` defintion. It should be used in the preamble like `\usepackage`.

Comment: OK! Thank you, Qrrbrbirlbel